# Form event on HTML5 validation failed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I must have missed something.

I have a form:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="field" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

And I want to add a special behavior when then user clicks on the `submit` button without filling the `required` field. I have jQuery so my intuition wrote:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  console.log('Adding special behavior');
});
```

but this is not triggered. Looked for `$('form').on('validate')` or something, but could not find anything.

Ain't there any event triggered at this step? Do I have to remove the `required` and handle all the validation manually? That would be surprising!

Thanks

---

EDIT: this is no duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123236/validate-form-before-submit-jquery) since I don't (want to) use `jquery.validate.js` and my question doesn't rely on jQuery (I happen to use it but this simply helps for clarity). It's the HTML5 behavior that I wanted to clarify.

Comment: try onsubmit event in form tag and return false in function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your input has a required attribute, the browser make sure the input is valid before submitting the form. Therefore, your event is never triggered.

However, you could add a [novalidate](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) attribute to your form to bypass the browser validation and perform your manual validation while keeping the required attribute on the inputs.

```
<form action="/" method="post" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="field" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Also, if you want to stop the form from submitting normally, you have to do a `preventDefault` in your event.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Adding special behavior');

});
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nyecdfrj/

Comment: Interesting that my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123236/validate-form-before-submit-jquery) indeed, but the answer there is not satisfactory while yours is awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the form onsubmit:

```
< form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="test()">

function test() {
return false; //never submit
}
```